# Make Thunderbird request certificate on port 993, not 443

Tags: linux, thunderbird, certificate, imap, tls

I am trying to create a certificate exception in Thunderbird, for a specific server `<servername>` (I am specifically asking not to be lectured about how it would be better to have an acceptable certificate for the server, I am aware of that and I cannot do anything about it). When I try adding a certificate exception for `<servername>`, `imap://<servername>` or `imaps://<servername>` in the certificate manager, I see in Wireshark that TB tries to connect to TCP 443 on the server, but the server is (probably) configured not to answer on anything but 993 (TCP SYN gets not response). If I try setting an exception for `<servername>:993` or `https://<servername>:993` (as per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/106766/how-can-i-get-thunderbird-to-import-a-secure-ldap-certificate/107330#107330)), then it just tells me "no available information - impossible to get the identification status for this site" (translated from French). In this case it doesn't even try connecting to the server, on any port.

How can I make Thunderbird obtain the certificate from the server using port TCP 993, or alternatively, how can I create a certificate exception using the certificate file I have on my computer (instead of retrieving it from the server)?

Just for the context: currently, when trying to retrieve e-mails from this server, TB doesn't even ask me for an exception anymore. It just sends an "Encrypted alert" message at the end of the handshake, then a TCP RST, and then it starts again, on a loop, without user interaction. The server certificate it gets during handshake is the one I expect.

I'm using Thunderbird 91.7.0 on Linux.

Additional information:

- I have another Linux machine with another Thunderbird, able to work with this server (with a certificate exception). Importing cert9.db and key4.db from this working install does not solve the issue;
- Client and server do have a common cipher suite on which they agree (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - 0xc02f).

Comment: Are you sure it’s not working because of the certificate? It could also be due to unsupported ciphers or TLS versions.

Comment: Port 443 is for HTTPS, port 993 is for secure IMAP, which seems right. I'm not sure that this is the problem.

Comment: @harrymc : I have working exceptions on servers for port 993, why can't I do it for this one? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @DanielB : Nah, client and server do agree on a cipher suite (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - 0xc02f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make Thunderbird obtain the certificate from the server using port TCP 993, or alternatively, how can I create a certificate exception using the certificate file I have on my computer (instead of retrieving it from the server)?

In the "Manage Certificates" dialog, it looks like there is an option to import the certificate manually under the "Authorities" tab:

[image: screenshot of thunderbird certificate manager dialog, Authorities tab, red circle around "import" button]

If you import the self-signed certificate here (and, potentially, "Edit Trust" on it and tick the boxes in that dialog), does that enable you to get mail from the server?

**Update:**

Looks like there are a couple bugs listed around certificate manager:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=thunderbird+self-signed

- 2017: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1370022
- 2021-01: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1684782
- 2021-10: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1737609

I'll poke around a bit for a potential work-around that *doesn't* involve having to pour over Mozilla's gargantuan code-bases in order to hunt down the bug(s) and patch it(them).

**Potential Solution:**

Huzah! What a PITA this was. Initially, my goal was to somehow, someway, get certificate exceptions into Thunderbird at all. I was able to do so.

1. Load up Thunderbird and fire up the Error Console (Tools > Developer Tools > Error Console).
2. Execute this at the console: `openTab("contentTab",{url:"https://expired.badssl.com/"})`
3. Observe a security error, with text that says "Secure connection failed" and a blue link for "Or you can add an exception..." that doesn't actually do anything.
4. Then, go back to the cert manager in preferences.
5. In the Servers section, click "Add Exception", and put in "https://expired.badssl.com" and then click "Get Certificate".
6. You should get something like "Outdated Information" and "The certificate is not currently valid".
7. Click "Confirm Security Exception".
8. At this point, you can exit the cert manager.
9. At this point, if you try to load the page via the error console again, it may or may not work. Sometimes it did for me, sometimes it didn't. However, stopping and starting thunderbird ensured that it did work.
10. Once I confirmed that I was able to close, re-open, and visit the https://expired.badssl.com URL via the error console (it's a big red page with large white text that reads "expired.badssl.com"), I visited the profile directory. Mine was here:

`C:\Users\Preston Maness\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\ij5cen6z.default-release`

11. In this folder was a "cert_override.txt" file now! It looked something like this:

```
# PSM Certificate Override Settings file
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
wrong.host.badssl.com:443:  OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  90:94:C2:BD:FA:69:7B:45:03:DA:AD:11:67:EB:20:A5:A4:71:EA:98:D0:1F:76:54:72:63:FC:9E:AE:C7:C8:F2 M   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAATwrwbNo3pgtkE0LwoesdWf0wTTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFTATBgNVBAoTDERpZ2lDZXJ0IEluYzEnMCUGA1UEAxMeRGlnaUNlcnQgU0hBMiBTZWN1cmUgU2VydmVyIENB
expired.badssl.com:443: OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  BA:10:5C:E0:2B:AC:76:88:8E:CE:E4:7C:D4:EB:79:41:65:3E:9A:C9:93:B6:1B:2E:B3:DC:C8:20:14:D2:1B:4F T   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAk0rnlUn6mr4/EA8XpHjhaQkwgZAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRswGQYDVQQIExJHcmVhdGVyIE1hbmNoZXN0ZXIxEDAOBgNVBAcTB1NhbGZvcmQxGjAYBgNVBAoTEUNPTU9ETyBDQSBMaW1pdGVkMTYwNAYDVQQDEy1DT01PRE8gUlNBIERvbWFpbiBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIFNlY3VyZSBTZXJ2ZXIgQ0E=
```

Notice the "expired.badssl.com:443" entry followed by what looks like some identifiers, the hash of the certificate, and some base64-encoded data.

12. At least [one Thunderbird user](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1308004) was then able to edit this entry to use the proper email-related ports (instead of 443) and then was able to send and receive mail without certificate problems:

> Copy the above to a new line, and the only thing you need to change is the port number. In my case, I changed it from port 143 to port 465 since that's what I use on the hmailserver program for the SMTP port. Then save the file. Now now the file looks like this:
> my.mail.server:143  OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  CE:D6:4C: (buch of key gibberish after this)
> my.mail.server:465  OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  CE:D6:4C: (buch of key gibberish after this)
> Now you can restart Thunderbird and when you check the certificate exceptions you'll see the cert listed twice - once for the incoming port and again for the outgoing port. I now have no problem receiving "or" sending e-mail through my end-to-end encrypted hmailserver program.

---

In your particular scenario though, it doesn't sound like you'd be able to do this directly. Your target server isn't listening on 443. But you mentioned that you have the certificate file itself. There is a project here for crafting these certificate override lines that takes a hostname and cert file:

https://github.com/Osmose/firefox-cert-override

I was able to run this script and get it to spit out what looks like valid content for `cert_override.txt` (albeit with a different domain, google.com, since I don't have your PEM file):

Command:

```
$ firefox-cert-override google.com:443=/tmp/google.pem google.com:443=/tmp/google.pem
```

Output:

```
# PSM Certificate Override Settings file
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
google.com:443  OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  DE:EF:77:F6:32:11:74:46:D5:7A:79:78:39:F6:ED:3C:C2:9A:1D:6C:B8:07:05:18:B9:5A:84:71:4F:75:ED:70 MUT AAAAAAAAAAAAAAARAAAASADaXCSq7j0ZmBIAAAAABaYdMEYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMSIwIAYDVQQKExlHb29nbGUgVHJ1c3QgU2VydmljZXMgTExDMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpHVFMgQ0EgMUMz
google.com:443  OID.2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  DE:EF:77:F6:32:11:74:46:D5:7A:79:78:39:F6:ED:3C:C2:9A:1D:6C:B8:07:05:18:B9:5A:84:71:4F:75:ED:70 MUT AAAAAAAAAAAAAAARAAAASADaXCSq7j0ZmBIAAAAABaYdMEYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMSIwIAYDVQQKExlHb29nbGUgVHJ1c3QgU2VydmljZXMgTExDMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpHVFMgQ0EgMUMz
```

(I used the same entry twice just to show how the script takes multiple inputs; you'd have different host:port combinations, though I imagine the cert file would be the same for each)

I suspect that if you were to run that script, with your cert file, and with the desired ports (993, 25/587/465/whatever) on the host, that you'd get a `cert_override.txt` file that you could put into the profile, close Thunderbird, then re-open Thunderbird and have things working again.

Or at least, I really really hope so :)

Comment: No, it works only for a CA certificate. The server certificate I have is refused (the CA signing it is properly imported)

Comment: Odd. If the Certificate Authority is imported and trusted (edit: and all intermediate CAs between the root and the server certificate), then I would expect any server certificates signed by (the root or its intermediates) to be accepted transparently, without needing to add further exceptions.

Comment: Well, this particular situation is really messed up and there are very good reasons for TB to reject the certificate (both the server and CA certificates are expired, yay). I just want the opportunity to add an exception (until proper certs are deployed on the server). It is odd that TB doesn't obtain the certificate properly when trying to do so.

Comment: Ah. That would explain why having the CA in the store isn't enough (since it's expired). And yes, it does sound like a bug in the UI in that case. Have you tried using `imaps://<servername>:993` as the URL? My hope is Thunderbird will query the server on 993 rather than try 443 if the port is set explicitly, since `imaps://<servername>` does at least try to talk to the server (on the wrong port).

Comment: No, sorry, I guess I made a mistake in my question, with `imaps://<servername>` TB tells me that it tries to get the certificate but doesn't actually send anything to the server (on any port). It does the same with your suggestion (which I had not tried, thanks).

Comment: @Eusebius I updated my answer. If its approach doesn't work, then I don't know what will :P

Comment: It worked! For some reason the entry generated for the server name wasn't accepted by Thunderbird, but the one generated for the server IP did (well, on top of other issues, the server name doesn't resolve through "natural means"). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this as well while trying to connect to a locally run Dovecot server (that by default uses a self-signed certificate).
Given that the TB interface to add certificate exceptions only accepts "sites" that start with `https://`, I configured Dovecot to run an additional process on port 443. Then the exception could be added without problems.

For the record I added this to `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`:

```
  inet_listener https {
    port = 443
    ssl = yes
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be bumping into bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1764770 "Suddenly Thunderbird does not retrieve imap mail - cert override dialog doesn't come up" also discussed at https://old.reddit.com/r/Thunderbird/comments/wlx2yp/tb_does_not_work_with_my_imap_server_after/

According to the comment https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1764770#c9 "Add Exception. Dialog hangs at 'Attempting to identify this site'."

This was noticed with TB 102, but perhaps it started earlier.  According to the bug report a fix may have been committed for TB branch 105, which has not been released yet at the time of this writing.

In the mean time the work-around that worked for me with TB 102.8 is modifying the TB Config Editor setting `network.security.ports.banned.override` to `993` as described in the comment https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1764770#c49

Once I did that and restarted TB I still had to manually open the 'Manage Certificates...' dialog but was able to add a new security exception via the 'Add Security Exception' dialog.  I entered 'servername:993' for 'Location', clicked 'Get Certificate', and TB did load it and the 'Confirm Security Exception' button became enabled, so no more hanging there.  So clicked that, then clicked 'Get Messages' for mailbox, and was able to load the messages.